# iOS - Terminated due to memory issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks

I'm having a memory issue with one specific ViewController and memory. When I launch my app in debug mode, it launches with 40mb memory usage. (I have no idea if this is already a lot or not -- what is common?). Then, when I open this specific view, it spikes up to about 120mb. The issue is, when I pop this view (with the navigationController popViewController), the memory stays up at 120mb. And then, when I re-open it, it spikes to 200mb (a 80mb increase every time).
With other similar ViewController it spikes up to 120mb too, but when I close the view, it goes back down to more or less 40mb.

The problem is that this specific view contains quite a bit of code (about 1000 lines...) and it's impossible for me to post everything here.

What methods should I use to specifically locate the issue in xCode?

Comment: You could be abandoning or leaking memory. Use the Allocations and / or the Leaks Instruments to track down the issue.

Comment: Once you've fixed the leak and understand the code better, you should pause and refactor the class into smaller classes.  It'll benefit you in the long run. 

Comment: Search on "leak". Use Instruments / Leaks. Use Xcode memory graph. Look for common causes of leaks, e.g. notification, repeating timer, stored closure referring to self.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone I might be able to help with this:

use the tools in xCode as recommended. There are some great tutorials online.

In my case it was an issue with an [NSTimer] which kept a strong reference to my view, so it never got released afterwards, thus stacking up memory. Make sure to stop your time when you pop a view.